# Dependent drop-downs not working correctly with apex:actionSupport

Tags: apex, visualforce, ajax, actionsupport, field-dependencies

I have 3 custom fields (select fields) Question1 , 2 and 3 . There is a dependency between Question1 and 2 ; and between 2 and 3 (using Field dependencies).

I have the following VF page :

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardController="LiveChatTranscript" extensions="preChatRemoting_Con" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" >
 <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Salesforce1Styling, 'assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.css')}" />
<apex:form >



         <div >
             <label  for="HelpSection">What do you need help with? </label>   
             <!-- Question 1 -->

              <apex:actionRegion >
              <apex:inputField value="{!LiveChatTranscript.Question1__c}" id="Question1"   taborderhint="6" styleClass="slds-select"  >
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="CompletePanel" />
              </apex:inputField>
              </apex:actionRegion>  



              <apex:actionRegion >
              <apex:inputField value="{!LiveChatTranscript.Question2__c}" id="Question2"  taborderhint="7" styleClass="slds-select"  >
                  <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="CompletePanel" />
              </apex:inputField>
             </apex:actionRegion>



              <apex:actionRegion >
              <apex:inputField value="{!LiveChatTranscript.Question3__c}" id="Question3"  taborderhint="8" styleClass="slds-select"  >
                   <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="CompletePanel" />
              </apex:inputField>
                   </apex:actionRegion> 


          </div>


           <apex:outputPanel id="CompletePanel"> 
          <div class="form-group">
              <input id="referenceNumber"  name="liveagent.prechat:ReferenceNumber"   
                     tabindex="9" class="label-slide" type="text" placeholder="Reference Number / Serial Number" />
              <label for="referenceNumber">Reference Number / Serial Number</label>
            </div>



                {! Now() } <br/> 
                Question1__c : {!LiveChatTranscript.Question1__c}  <br/>
                 Question2__c : {!LiveChatTranscript.Question2__c} <br/>
                 Question3__c : {!LiveChatTranscript.Question3__c} <br/>


      </apex:outputPanel>      

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

If i add all 3 the dropdown values do not show correctly in the "Complete Panel" as shown below:
[image]

But if i comment out the 3rd dropdown , it shows the selected values correctly :

[image]

What am i missing here ? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the event from "onchange" to "onclick" did the trick.